# How to compress only symlink from directory as tar.gz?

Tags: linux

I need linux command to compress only symlink from some directory such as this screnshot.
I do not need to compress as name. like this

```
tar -czf /tmp/test.tar.gz cars movies plugin 2.txt 10.txt
```

Because the symlink names are variable and not fixed
[image]

Comment: can you explain what you mean with "compress symlinks"? I don't understand? Symlinks are included as such in the tar archive and there's nothing special to compress about them; generally, tar archives are compressed *as whole*, not per entry. "names are variable and not fixed" err, it's not clear what you mean here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the command line, one solves complex tasks by combining multiple commands. If we know there are no spaces and special characters in the names of the symlinks, one can simply use `find` with [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```bash
tar -czf /tmp/test.tar.gz `find -maxdepth 1 -type l`
```

This won't work for example with spaces or semicolons in a name. In this case, a simple solution is to write the list to a temporary file:

```bash
TMPLIST=`mktemp`
find -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 > $TMPLIST
tar -czf /tmp/test.tar.gz --null --files-from $TMPLIST
rm $TMPLIST
```

Comment: space characters would only be a problem if it was included in `$IFS` (as it is by default) as command substitutions are split on characters of `$IFS`. `$IFS` by default contains space, tab and newline (and nul in zsh), so those characters would obviously be a problem if they occurred in file names. You do *need* to have newline included in `$IFS` as that's what you want to split the output of `find` on. Globbing characters (`*`, `?`,...) would also be a problem in bash and most Bourne-like shells, but not semicolon.

Comment: Thank you. This work fine `tar -czf /tmp/test.tar.gz `find -maxdepth 1 -type l``

Comment: Why not use a pipe? `find -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 | tar -czf /tmp/test.tar.gz --null --files-from -`

Comment: @StephenKitt Because reading from stdin via specifying a file "-" is not documented in the man page entry for `--files-from` (gnu tar v1.34 on my system)

Comment: @JoachimWagner for GNU software you always need to check the info pages rather than the man page; in this case, the section on [Reading Names from a File](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html).

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can use the `@` glob qualifier to restrict glob expansions to files of type *symlink*:

```
tar -czf file.tar.gz -- *(@)
```

To also include hidden ones, add the `D` (for `D`ot-file) qualifier:

```
tar -czf file.tar.gz -- *(D@)
```

In other shells, you could use `find` to find the files of type *symlink* and pass them to `tar`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type l -exec tar -zcf file.tar.gz {} +
```

But note some differences compared to the zsh approach:

- the hidden files are included and it takes some:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -type l -exec tar -zcf file.tar.gz {} +
  ```

  to exclude them reliably.
- the list of file is not sorted.
- a `./` prefix is added to the archive members (and it's why we don't need the `--`).
- if there are a lot of matching files, `find` may end up calling `tar` several times which would mean `file.tar.gz` would only include the files from the last run. (in those cases, with the zsh approach, you may end-up getting a *argument list too longer* error instead).

With the GNU implementations of `find`, `sort` and `tar`, and `ifne` from moreutils, you can address those by doing:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -type l -printf '%P\0' |
  sort -z |
  ifne tar -zcf file.tar.gz --null -T -
```

Where:

- we use `-printf '%P\0'` to print the paths of the files relative to the starting directory (`.`), so for instance it prints `link` instead of `./link`. It's NUL delimited as 0 is the only byte value that can't occur in a file path.
- `sort -z` sorts those NUL-delimited records lexically as per the locale's collation order like for zsh globs.
- we pass that list to `tar` via a pipe on its stdin rather than as arguments to avoid the system's limit on the size of the arguments.
- `ifne` is needed to cover the case where there's no file, in which case if find that without it GNU `tar` 1.34 at least seems to be creating a mostly-sparse 10KiB `file.tar.gz` filled with zeros.

In any case, remember that one shouldn't create files with fixed name in world-writable directories such as `/tmp` as that's a security risk.

Comment: (D@) dies not work `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('` but this command work fine `find . ! -name . -prune -type l -exec tar -zcf file.tar.gz {} +` Thank you

Comment: I did say with zsh, not sh